# How to setup Load balancing in EC2(wm where our services .war/.db are deployed into diff EC2 vm) in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to setup Load balancing in EC2(wm where our services .war/.db are deployed into diff EC2 vm) in aws even after setting the Auto scaling & ELB managed service in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

If you already set the Auto scaling group and ELB, maybe you're asking how to configure the routing algorithm of the load balancing? Default is round robin:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html

Or you're asking how to plug ec2 instances to the configured ELB, and then, as Asri said, put the ec2 instances in a target group, and attach the target group to the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Application load balancer attached to a target group which contains your EC2 vms: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html